# File upload not working in IE, but works in FF, Chrome, and Safari

Tags: php

I'm stumped.  I've created an upload image process that works in every browser except Internet Explorer.  I didn't check IE7 but IE8 seems to not check the file extension.  I keep getting the error "you must upload a jpg, gif, bmp."

```
  /* image uploading */
  $target_path = "img/";
  $image = $_FILES['crebusimage'];
  $image['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($image['name']);
  $target_path .= $crebustime."_".$image['name'];
  $valid_types = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/bmp", "image/gif", "image/jpe", "image/jfif", "image/png");

  $field = 'crebusimage';
  if(strlen($image['name']) == 0){
    $form->setError($field, "*please choose an image");
  }elseif(!in_array($image['type'], $valid_types)){
    $form->setError($field, "*You must upload a jpg, gif, or bmp");
  }else{
    $busimg = $crebustime."_".$image['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $target_path);
  }

    <td><b>Business Logo<br />(100Kb or less 100x100px)</b></td>
    <td><input type="file" name="crebusimage" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" /></td>
    <td><?php echo $form->error('crebusimage'); ?></tD>
```

How can I make this thing work in evil IE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See what you're getting in your $_FILES array by executing this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_FILES);
echo '</pre>';
```

and use [getimagesize](http://www.php.net/getimagesize) to determine the image type, as mime types can be spoofed as @Juddling has correctly pointed out.

Comment: I'm getting:
    Array
    (
        [name] => image.jpeg
        [type] => image/pjpeg
        [tmp_name] => /var/tmp/php78z4j9
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 3026
)

What's with the pjpeg?  Rather than jpeg...

Comment: @ivannovak - I can see the problem now, there is no pjpeg mime type in your $valid_types array. Add "image/pjpeg" and it will work!

Answer (score 4):

If you're uploading jpegs, they generally get sent with the mimetype image/pjpeg in IE.

Specifically, I've encountered this problem with csv files. Windows machines will give you varying mimetypes depending on what you have installed to open csv files. /endgripe ;)

Comment: So in IE, just for the sake of being difficult, adds a p to the beginning of file types?  Thanks MS...

Comment: Tell me about it. I've not trusted mimetypes for a while now. Alternatively, one could just look for an instance of jpeg, png, bmp, or gif in the mimetype string and that would work as look as it's != -1

Answer (score 1):

You should be checking the file extensions, not the headers sent along with the image. Maybe IE doesn't send these as they can be faked.

Comment: How would I check the file extension, I thought that was what I was doing with image['type'].

Comment: $filename = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
     $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
   
     if($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "png" || $ext == "gif") { // then check your extention

     }

Comment: no. You would be suprised how many png/gif's are saved as JPG and visa versa. You really want to look at the header.

Comment: What about if i upload image.php and spoof the header as image/gif?